# Openrowset vs. Linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

In my work area we have 100+ MS SQL databases across the country from where we need to query data back to a single SQL db. We can do this either by using `OpenRowSet` or `LinkedServer`. But which one should be used.

**Openrowset** is ad-hoc. So connection have to be established every time openrowset is called. This should have some extra overhead on performance.

On the other hand **Linked Server** is persistent. So no need to establish connection every time (i guess). But the central server does have to have all those linked servers added to it. Will adding so many linked servers have any negative impact on the server?

Bottom line is that for connecting to a lot of servers on monthly basis, which will be better approach? openrowset or linked server?

Comment: In the past I've had bad experiences with linked servers using complex databases. In the end we had to rewrite our code to query each database one at a time (multi-threaded) and merge the results. Here's a technet article about the issue with linked servers: http://blogs.technet.com/b/pfelatam/archive/2011/09/07/linked-server-behavior-when-used-on-join-clauses.aspx

Comment: What if I only use `Operquery` with linked server?

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, OpenRowSet executes the query on the remote server, whereas Linked Server makes the join locally.  (Much more resource-intensive than 'connection' concerns.)