# SSMS - Linked Servers - Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, ssms, linked-server

I am hoping someone might be able to assist me with this.  We have recently got an Azure SQL server setup and we have an existing externally hosted MySQL server

I am looking for a way to link these to allow SSMS to query against the MySQL database, which I believe can be done using a linked server in SSMS.  The issue is that my SSMS seems to not have the options I would expect [existing SSMS Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwfGU.png) like Server Objects and linked servers

Does anyone know why this isn't visible, I heard it was due to this being an Azure server and not a hosted SQL server

Any ideas?

Gratitude in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to link these to allow SSMS to query against the MySQL database, which I believe can be done using a linked server in SSMS. The issue is that my SSMS seems to not have the options I would expect existing SSMS Options like Server Objects and linked servers

You cannot.

*Azure SQL* does not supported Linked Servers. Only on-prem SQL Server and *Azure SQL **Managed Instance*** supports that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

---

[However you *can* use `OPENROWSET` to query any OLE-DB data-source from Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but [this is not the same as a Linked Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512706/openrowset-vs-linked-server).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I will give the OPENROWSET a try

Comment: Hello, I have had no luck with OPENROWSET so I have purchased a SQL managed instance which I am also having trouble with.  When you setup a DSN to use with a managed SQL instance, do you have to set it up and install the ODBC drivers on the virtual machine that is hosting the managed instance?